# How to release java objects from memory using releaseJavaObject() function

Tags: java, .net, jvm, handle

I'm trying to control a calculator interface which based on Java Oracle. My problem is the memory leakage.

Let me explain what is happening. With 2 class,`JabApi` and `JabHelpers`, I'm making an object of `AccessibleTreeItem` class which is located in JabHelpers.

Then doing some operations such as click to a button on the calculator in a for loop. After that, I'm trying to release memory using `MyDispose()`  method that use the `releaseJavaObject()` method is located in JabHelpers but I could not observe a decrement in memory.

I am not sure the `releaseJavaObject()` is working fine because after the javaTree.`MyDispose()` method, when try to click another button (button3) but it does not any changes on the calculator.

What is my main problem in the JabApi and JabHelpers class? I don't know may be problem is related with the `releaseJavaObject()` importing parameters? Could it be? May be it is related with the `GetAccessibleContextInfo(Int32 vmID, IntPtr currentPtr, out AccessibleContextInfo currentContext, AccessibleTreeItem parentItem, int level, string lineage)` method is located in JapHelper, I have no idea.

Please, support me. Thank you!

Main code below:

```
namespace JabApiCsharpSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //JabApi.Windows_run();
            JabHelpers.Init();
            int vmID = 0;
            IntPtr hwnd = (IntPtr)3346002;//that is the handleWindow number given by Windows
            JabHelpers.AccessibleTreeItem javaTree = null;
            JabHelpers.AccessibleTreeItem button1 = null;
            JabHelpers.AccessibleTreeItem button2 = null;
            JabHelpers.AccessibleTreeItem button = null;
            JabHelpers.AccessibleTreeItem button3 = null;

         
            //javaTree = JabHelpers.GetComponentTreeByTitle("ELİNT", out vmID);



            int index = 50;

            javaTree = JabHelpers.GetComponentTree(hwnd, out vmID);

            button1 = javaTree.children[0].children[1];
            button2 = button1.children[1].children[2];
            button = button2.children[1].children[3];
            button3 = button2.children[1].children[4];

            JabHelpers.DoAccessibleActions(vmID, button3.acPtr, "click");
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            {              

                JabHelpers.DoAccessibleActions(vmID, button.acPtr, "click");
                            }

            javaTree.MyDispose(javaTree, vmID);
            
         
            JabHelpers.DoAccessibleActions(vmID, button3.acPtr, "click");
         
        }


    }
}
```

Here is a part of JabHelper class:

```
public static AccessibleTreeItem GetComponentTreeByTitle(String title, out Int32 vmID)
        {
            IntPtr hwnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, title);
            return GetComponentTree(hwnd, out vmID);
        }

        public static AccessibleTreeItem GetComponentTree(IntPtr hWnd, out Int32 vmID)
        {
            screenContents.Clear();
            screenContentsString = string.Empty;

            AccessibleTreeItem accessibleTreeItem = new AccessibleTreeItem();
            vmID = 0;
            if (JabApi.isJavaWindow(hWnd) == 1)
            {
                unsafe
                {
                    IntPtr acPtr;

                    if (JabApi.getAccessibleContextFromHWND(hWnd, out vmID, out acPtr))
                    {

                        AccessibleContextInfo ac = new AccessibleContextInfo();
                        accessibleTreeItem = GetAccessibleContextInfo(vmID, acPtr, out ac, null, 0, string.Empty); // RECURSION SEED

                        return accessibleTreeItem;
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

 private static AccessibleTreeItem GetAccessibleContextInfo(Int32 vmID, IntPtr currentPtr, out AccessibleContextInfo currentContext, AccessibleTreeItem parentItem, int level, string lineage)
        {
            unsafe
            {
                // Allocate global memory space for the size of AccessibleContextInfo and store the address in acPtr
                IntPtr acPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(new AccessibleContextInfo()));
                try
                {

                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(new AccessibleContextInfo(), acPtr, true);
                    if (JabApi.getAccessibleContextInfo(vmID, currentPtr, acPtr))
                    {
                        currentContext = (AccessibleContextInfo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(acPtr, typeof(AccessibleContextInfo));
                        if (!ReferenceEquals(currentContext, null))
                        {
                            AccessibleTreeItem newItem = BuildAccessibleTree(currentPtr, currentContext, parentItem);

                            if (!ReferenceEquals(newItem, null))
                            {
                                //Checks to see if current object has any text items.
                                if (currentContext.accessibleText == true)
                                {
                                    AccessibleTextItemsInfo textItem;
                                    //Gets text items.
                                    textItem = GetAccessibleTextInfo(vmID, currentPtr);
                                    newItem.textValue = textItem.sentence;

                                    string treeInfo = Repeat("\t", level) + currentContext.name + " = \"" + textItem.sentence + "\"";
                                    screenContentsString += treeInfo + Environment.NewLine;
                                    Debug.Print(treeInfo);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    string treeInfo = Repeat("\t", level) + currentContext.name;
                                    screenContentsString += treeInfo + Environment.NewLine;
                                    Debug.Print(treeInfo);
                                }


                                //Start collecting children
                                int nextLevel = level + 1;
                                for (int i = 0; i < currentContext.childrenCount; i++)
                                {
                                    string lineageInfo = Repeat("\t", level) + level.ToString() + " Child " + i.ToString() + " Lineage = {" + lineage + "}";
                                    screenContentsString += lineageInfo + Environment.NewLine;
                                    Debug.Print(lineageInfo);

                                    string currentlineage;
                                    if (lineage == string.Empty)
                                        currentlineage = i.ToString();
                                    else
                                        currentlineage = lineage + ", " + i.ToString();

                                    if (currentContext.role_en_US != "unknown" && currentContext.states_en_US.Contains("visible")) // Note the optomization here, I found this get me to an acceptable speed
                                    {
                                        AccessibleContextInfo childContext = new AccessibleContextInfo();
                                        IntPtr childPtr = JabApi.getAccessibleChildFromContext(vmID, currentPtr, i);

                                        GetAccessibleContextInfo(vmID, childPtr, out childContext, newItem, nextLevel, currentlineage);

                                    }

                                }
                            }

                            return newItem;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentContext = new AccessibleContextInfo();
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (acPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
                        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(acPtr);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

public void MyDispose(AccessibleTreeItem parent, int vmID)
            {
                if (parent.children.Count == 0)
                {
                    JabApi.releaseJavaObject(vmID, parent.acPtr);
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < parent.childrenCount; i++)
                    {
                        parent.children[i].MyDispose(parent.children[i], vmID);
                    }
                    JabApi.releaseJavaObject(vmID, parent.acPtr);
                }
            }
```

Here is a part of JabApi code :

You can see the releaseJavaObject() metod is imported in there.

```
 public static class JabApi
    {

        public const String WinAccessBridgeDll = @"WindowsAccessBridge-64.dll";
        public const Int32 MAX_STRING_SIZE = 1024;
        public const Int32 SHORT_STRING_SIZE = 256;

        #region Event Handlers
        #region EventDLLImport
        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setMouseClickedFP(MouseClickedDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setMouseEnteredFP(MouseEnteredDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setMouseExitedFP(MouseExitedDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setMousePressedFP(MousePressedDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setMouseReleasedFP(MouseReleasedDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setFocusGainedFP(FocusGainedDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setFocusLostFP(FocusLostDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setCaretUpdateFP(CaretUpdateDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setJavaShutdownFP(JavaShutDownDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setMenuCanceledFP(MenuCanceledDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setMenuDeselectedFP(MenuDeselectedDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setMenuSelectedFP(MenuSelectedDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setPopupMenuCanceledFP(PopupMenuCanceledDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setPopupMenuWillBecomeInvisibleFP(PopupMenuWillBecomeInvisibleDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setPopupMenuWillBecomeVisibleFP(PopupMenuWillBecomeVisibleDelegate fp);
        
        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setPropertyActiveDescendentChangeFP(PropertyActiveDescendentChangeDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setPropertyCaretChangeFP(PropertyCaretChangeDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setPropertyChangeFP(PropertyChangeDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setPropertyChildChangeFP(PropertyChildChangeDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setPropertyDescriptionChangeFP(PropertyDescriptionChangeDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setPropertyNameChangeFP(PropertyNameChangeDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setPropertySelectionChangeFP(PropertySelectionChangeDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setPropertyStateChangeFP(PropertyStateChangeDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setPropertyTableModelChangeFP(PropertyTableModelChangeDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setPropertyTextChangeFP(PropertyTextChangeDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setPropertyValueChangeFP(PropertyValueChangeDelegate fp);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setPropertyVisibleDataChangeFP(PropertyVisibleDataChangeDelegate fp);
        #endregion EventDLLImport
        #region Event Delegates

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void PropertyChangeDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string property, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string oldValue, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string newValue);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void JavaShutDownDelegate(System.Int32 vmID);


        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void FocusGainedDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void FocusLostDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac);


        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void CaretUpdateDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac);


        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void MouseClickedDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void MouseEnteredDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void MouseExitedDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void MousePressedDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void MouseReleasedDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac);


        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void MenuCanceledDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void MenuDeselectedDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void MenuSelectedDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void PopupMenuCanceledDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void PopupMenuWillBecomeInvisibleDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void PopupMenuWillBecomeVisibleDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void PropertyNameChangeDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string oldName, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string newName);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void PropertyDescriptionChangeDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string oldDescription, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string newDescription);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void PropertyStateChangeDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string oldState, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string newState);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void PropertyValueChangeDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string oldValue, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string newValue);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void PropertySelectionChangeDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void PropertyTextChangeDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void PropertyCaretChangeDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac,
        Int32 oldPosition, Int32 newPosition);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void PropertyVisibleDataChangeDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void PropertyChildChangeDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac,
        IntPtr oldChild, IntPtr newChild);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void PropertyActiveDescendentChangeDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac,
        IntPtr oldActiveDescendent, IntPtr newActiveDescendent);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void PropertyTableModelChangeDelegate(System.Int32 vmID, IntPtr jevent, IntPtr ac,
        IntPtr oldValue, IntPtr newValue);

        #endregion Event Delegates

        #endregion DLLImport - Functions

        //Inits the JAB.
        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void Windows_run();

        //Checks if window is JavaWindow.
        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static unsafe Int32 isJavaWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

        //Releases the specified java object.
        //[DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, EntryPoint = "releaseJavaObject", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public extern static void releaseJavaObject(Int32 vmID, IntPtr javaObject);

        //Sets the text of the given accessible context.
        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void setTextContents(Int32 vmID, IntPtr ac, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string text);

        //Gets basic version info about JVM/JAB
        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static void getVersionInfo(Int32 vmID, IntPtr versionInfo);

        //Gets the next java window, where the hwnd passed is the previous window.
        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static unsafe IntPtr getNextJavaWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

        //Returns ac from window handle.
        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static unsafe Boolean getAccessibleContextFromHWND(IntPtr hwnd, out Int32 vmID, out IntPtr ac);

        //Returns handle from ac
        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static unsafe IntPtr getHWNDFromAccessibleContext(Int32 vmID, IntPtr ac);

        //Compares two objects
        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static unsafe Boolean isSameObject(Int32 vmID, IntPtr ac1, IntPtr ac2);

        //Returns an AccessibleContext object that represents the point given, offset by window coordinates.
        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static unsafe Boolean getAccessibleContextAt(Int32 vmID, IntPtr acparent, Int32 x, Int32 y, out IntPtr ac);

        //Returns an AccessibleContext object that represents the nth child of the object ac, where n is specified by the value index.
        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static unsafe IntPtr getAccessibleChildFromContext(Int32 vmID, IntPtr ac, Int32 index);

        //Returns an AccessibleContext object that represents the window with focus.
        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static unsafe Boolean getAccessibleContextWithFocus(void* window, out Int32 vmID, out IntPtr ac);

        //Returns an AccessibleContext object that represents the parent of the specified object.
        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static unsafe IntPtr getAccessibleParentFromContext(Int32 vmID, IntPtr ac);

        //Returns detailed information about an AccessibleContext object belonging to the JVM
        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static unsafe Boolean getAccessibleContextInfo(Int32 vmID, IntPtr accessibleContext, IntPtr acInfo);

        //**ACCESSIBLE TEXT FUNCTIONS
        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static unsafe Boolean getAccessibleTextInfo(Int32 vmID, IntPtr AccessibleContext, IntPtr textInfo, Int32 x, Int32 y);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static unsafe Boolean getAccessibleTextItems(Int32 vmID, IntPtr AccessibleContext, IntPtr textItems, Int32 index);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static unsafe Boolean getAccessibleTextAttributes(Int32 vmID, IntPtr AccessibleContext, Int32 index, IntPtr attributes);

        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static unsafe Boolean GetAccessibleTextSelectionInfo(Int32 vmID, IntPtr AccessibleContext, Int32 index, IntPtr textSelection);


        //
        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static Boolean getAccessibleActions(Int32 vmID, IntPtr AccessibleContext,  IntPtr ptrAccessibleActions);


        [DllImport(WinAccessBridgeDll, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static Boolean doAccessibleActions(Int32 vmID, IntPtr AccessibleContext, IntPtr actionsToDo, ref Int32 failure);


    }
}
```